# Is the Firebase Storage links which we get from getDownloadURL() dynamic or not

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

The imageurl in firebase Storage is it dynamic or not. I thought of storing the links once in Firebase Realtime Database as a property. But it would will be a problem if it's dynamic

Comment: Need more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download URL returned for a file in Cloud Storage by the Firebase SDK is permanent. The only way is can stop working is if the token it uses is revoked, for example if you revoke it from the Firebase console.